# Should I be seeing significant differences between std::bind and boost::bind?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio, stdbind

I'm exploring the support for C++11 on the g++-4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-2ubuntu~12.04, to be specific) and I seem to be finding differences.

In particular, if I comment out `#include <boost/bind.hpp>` and systematically replace occurrences of `boost::bind` with `std::bind` in the Boost ASIO async client example (taken from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp), the program no longer compiles.

Any explanation for this?

Comment: Can you please make a replacement that fails (preferably a single replacement) and post the modified code along with the compiler error?

Comment: I remember having seen different behaviour with nested binds. Don't recall the specifics right now. However, this is _not_ what you are running into here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <functional>
namespace boost {
    namespace asio {
        namespace stdplaceholders {
            static decltype ( :: std :: placeholders :: _1 ) & error = :: std :: placeholders :: _1;
            static decltype ( :: std :: placeholders :: _2 ) & bytes_transferred = :: std :: placeholders :: _2;
            static decltype ( :: std :: placeholders :: _2 ) & iterator = :: std :: placeholders :: _2;
            static decltype ( :: std :: placeholders :: _2 ) & signal_number = :: std :: placeholders :: _2;
        }
    }
}
```

and use `boost::asio::stdplaceholders::*` instead of `boost::asio::placeholders::*`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `boost::asio::placeholders` cannot be used in conjunction with `std::bind`. In the example you've linked to, the first call to `boost::bind` occurs in the following code:

```cpp
resolver_.async_resolve(query,
    boost::bind(&client::handle_resolve, this,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));
```

Simply replacing `boost::bind` with `std::bind` leads to a bunch of errors. To make it compile you need to replace `boost::asio::placeholders` with `std::placeholders`.

```
resolver_.async_resolve(query,
    std::bind(&client::handle_resolve, this,
      std::placeholders::_1,
      std::placeholders::_2));
```

Note that I haven't verified that the code is functionally the same after making these changes, only that it compiles.